# Kick window to the opposite monitor under TwinView?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors, window-manager, twinview

In Windows, under dual monitors, I can flip the active window to the same location on the other monitor by hitting Win+Shift+Left/Right. I can also "aero snap" the window to either half of the current monitor by dragging it to an edge or by hitting Win+Left/Right.

The second behaviour in both forms is available to me by default (Arch + Gnome Shell). How can I enable the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this feature was added (or perhaps just exposed) since I looked last.

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation

[image: Preferences]